# How to render ajax response to view

Tags: ajax, laravel

Here is my predicament: I need to render json response received from controller method. I do this by calling clicking on navbar item "List Articles" which activate method ajaxIndex(). Then tat method makes request to route which in turn call controller method also called ajaxIndex(). That method then gater all articles and sends it as a response. After that, that response i can't control, it just renders raw json ...
Navbar item:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/articles"  onclick="ajaxIndex(this)"> List Articles </a>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/articles', "ArticlesController@ajaxIndex");
```

Method in ArticlesController

```
public function ajaxIndex(Request $request)
    { 

        $var1 = $request->var1;
        $var2 = $request->var2;
        $elem = $request->elem;
        $currUser = auth()->user();
        $currUri = Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->uri();
        $articles = Article::orderBy("created_at","desc")->paginate(5);

        $html = view('articles.List Articles')->with(compact("articles", "var1", "var2", "elem", "currUser", "currUri"))->render();
        //return $request;
        return response()->json(["success"=> true, "html" => $html], 200);
        //return response()->json(["success"=> $articles,"var1"=> $var1, "var2"=> $var2, "elem"=> $elem, "currUser" => $currUser, "currUri" => $currUri], 200);

    }
```

and here my ajax method

```
function ajaxIndex(me,formId){

    let var1 = "gg";
    let var2 = "bruh";
    let token = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");
    let url = "/articles";

    if(formId){

        let form = $("#"+formId).serialize();

        console.log(form);

    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      headers:{
              "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
          },
      data: {/*
          var1: var1,
          var2: var2,
          elem: {
              id: me.id ? me.id : null,
              class: me.className ? me.className : null,
              value: me.value ? me.value : null,
              innerHTML: me.innerHTML ? me.innerHTML : null,
          }
        */},
      success: (data) => {
          console.log(data);
          $('#maine').html(JSON.parse(data.html));
      },
      error: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });         

}
```

How to render acquired data to particular view?
Now just renders json response alongside html. 
[image: jsonUnrendered]
My question is how to render response itself and where goes response from controller method. I tried console logging it when route is hit, but there is nothing in console. What is actual approach or what i need to change to achieve this?

**Addendum:** "For List Articles you will send ajax request to rest api where it returns array of objects(articles)". I assumed i needed to make ajax request, after being sent to appropriate blade, i should now display sent data? Am i getting wrong something? ...

**Edit1:**

Now when i go to any page in my app, for example:

```
http://articleapp.test/articles?page=2
```

it shows json response:

[image: page2Example]

**Edit2:**

I also modified my ajax method to correctly display current page for article listing. Problem start when try to go to next page.
Here is the code:

```
function ajaxIndex(me,formId){

    let token = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");
    let url = "/articles";

    if(formId){

        let form = $("#"+formId).serialize();

        console.log(form);

    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      headers:{
              "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
          },
      data: {},
      success: (data) => {
        console.log(data);

        let html = "<div class='container'>";
        let articleBody = "";
        let pagination = "<ul class='pagination'><li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#'>Previous</a></li>";
            if(data.articles.data.length > 0){

                for(let i=0;i<data.articles.current_page;i++){

                    let created_at = data.articles.data[i].created_at.replace(/-/g,"/").split(" ")[0];

                    html += "<div class='row' style='background-color: whitesmoke;'><div class='col-md-4 col-sm-4'><a href='/articles/"+data.articles.data[i].id+"'><img class='postCover postCoverIndex' src='/storage/images/"+data.articles.data[i].image+"'></a></div><div class='col-md-8 col-sm-8'><br>";

                    if(data.articles.data[i].body.length > 400){
                        articleBody = data.articles.data[i].body.substring(0, 400);
                       html += "<p>"+articleBody+"<a href='/articles/"+data.articles.data[i].id+"'>...Read more</a></p>";
                    }
                    else{
                        html += "<p>"+data.articles.data[i].body+"</p>";
                    }

                    html += "<small class='timestamp'>Written on "+created_at+" by "+data.articles.data[i].user.name+"</small></div></div><hr class='hrStyle'></hr>";
                    history.pushState(null, null, "/articles?page="+(i+1));
                }

                for(let i=0;i<data.articles.total;i++){
                    //console.log(data.articles.data[i].id);
                    pagination += "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='/articles?page="+(i+1)+"'>"+(i+1)+"</a></li>";
                }
                pagination += "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='#'>Next</a></li></ul>";
            }
        html+="<div class='d-flex' style='margin: 10px 0px;padding-top: 20px;'><div class='mx-auto' style='line-height: 10px;'>"+pagination+"</div></div></div>";
        $('#maine').html(html);


            //?page=2
      },
      error: (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });         

}
```

When i go to next page, it shows json response as i previously stated. Look in the image above. It won't render ...

Answer (score 0):

In this case ajax response should contain only the real content you want to get with the assynchronous request (html tags inside body). Your #maine element should be a div or another structure capable of having html child tags.

Ps.: If you want to render the ajax response like another page by changing header tags and maybe even the http content type then the response should be load inside an iframe tag.

**Edit: ** In pratice, delete the previous content before body tag in the view returned by ajax. And #maine must be a  to contain the ajax response.

Comment: Could you read addendum i wrote? I need to pick your brain about it.